# Print Frame Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, printing

I'm trying to print a pop up window using the following code :

```
window.frames['cInitChecksWindow_IFrame'].focus();
window.print();
```

When I view the print page the html of parent page is also passed along with pop-up window in Chrome. I just need the html of pop-up. This works fine in IE all versions with the same code.

Any help on how to print controls in Chrome will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.frames['cInitChecksWindow_IFrame'].print();
```

This will print only the iframe for me, however, if the iframe contains scrollbars, they will be printed while the hidden content will not.